# Hide cells in a range, not whole rows

Tags: excel, vba

I use the sub below but it hides the whole row. I would like to hide only some cells in the range, cells in `Range("N13:R13")` for example.

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim DataCount As Integer

With Workbooks("Mywb").Worksheets("Output")
    DataCount = .Range("N11:" & "N" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row

    For Each cell In .Range("N11:N" & DataCount)
            If InStr(cell.Value, "SMALL") > 0 Or InStr(cell.Value, "SM") > 0 Then
            .Range("N" & cell.Row & ":R" & cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

So how could I only hide the row between `N` and `R` columns, not the whole row? Best Regards

Comment: You use a `With` statement, but then use `Range`  instead of `.Range`?

Comment: @ErikEidt Ah my fault. Edited. But the problem still remains:)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can only hide a full column or a full row.  Hiding means that Excel collapses the row or column.  I don't know how it might hide a single cell, for example.

Comment: I also don't think you can hide a cell.  If you're trying to hide the data, maybe just set the font to the background color?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide a particular set of cells.
     `Hidden = True` should be used for the whole row/column. 
You can change the format of the cells with the below, to hide the content

`Range("N" & cell.Row & ":R" & cell.Row).NumberFormat = ";;;"`

But even doing so will show the contents in the formula bar.